# CSS divide between two divs

Tags: css, styling, shapes

I have been trying to create the following (attached), I have tried two div's but have to move one via relative position. I tried two `divs` with a third in absolute over but needed too much width to hide the join beneath!

This is the code:

```
<div class="title">
            <div class="left"></div>
            <div class="divide"></div>
            <div class="right"></div>
            <div class="name"><h1>Fuel Cards</h1></div>
        </div>

        <style>

            .title{
                position:relative;                  
            }

            .left{
                position:absolute;
                width:75%;
                left:0;
                background:red;
                height:80px;
            }

            .right{
                position:absolute;
                width:25%;
                right:0;
                background:black;
                height:80px;
            }

            .divide{
                width: 50px;
                height: 80px;
                background: white;
                -webkit-clip-path: polygon(75% 0%, 100% 0%, 25% 100%, 0% 100%);
                clip-path: polygon(75% 0%, 100% 0%, 25% 100%, 0% 100%);
                position:absolute;
                left:75%;
                z-index:1;
                float:left;
            }

            .name{
                position:relative;
                padding:10px 0;
                color:white;
                z-index: 1;
            }

            .shape{
                width: 50%;
                height: 280px;
                background: red;
                -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 100% 0%, 75% 100%, 0% 100%);
                clip-path: polygon(50% 0%, 100% 0%, 50% 100%, 0% 100%);
                float:left;
            }
            .shape2{
                width: 50%;
                height: 280px;
                background: black;
                -webkit-clip-path: polygon(25% 0%, 100% 0%, 100% 100%, 0% 100%);
                clip-path: polygon(50% 0%, 100% 0%, 50% 100%, 0% 100%);
                float:left;
                position: relative;
                right:115px;
            }
        </style>

        <div class="shape"></div>
        <div class="shape2"></div>
```

Can anyway help please?

[image]

Comment: Please show us the code that what you have tried so far?

Comment: Provide the code you are trying, please.

Comment: You can use CSS - Pseudo Elements for this type shapes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this with linear gradient although I'd probably use an SVG for better scaling.

```css
div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 75px;
  margin: 1em auto;
  background: linear-gradient(315deg, red, red 48%, white 48%, white 52%, black 52%);
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: Short and best solution.

Comment: Hi, Paulie_D, can you give the explanation. How to linear-gradient works.

Comment: Okay Thank you. :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's another method, which works in ie8, if needed.  Use before and after pseudo elements, with borders to draw triangles.

https://jsfiddle.net/xv661pe1/

```
<div class="fuelcards"></div>

.fuelcards { 
  background-color: #fff; width:100px; height:80px; position:relative; 
  border-left:40px solid red; 
  border-right:40px solid black; 
}
.fuelcards:before { 
content:"";
display:block; width:0; height:0; 
position:absolute; left:0; top:0; 
border:40px solid transparent; 
border-top-color:red; border-left-color:red;
}
.fuelcards:after { 
content:"";
display:block; width:0; height:0; 
position:absolute; right:0; top:0; 
border:40px solid transparent; 
border-bottom-color:black; border-right-color:black;
}
```